# "Grow" function for dynamic arrays generating an error

Tags: c++, dynamic-arrays

Beginner programmer here. 
The code below seems to always run into an error called: "pointer being freed was not allocated", and I can't figure out why.

A struct contains dynamic arrays to store integers and strings after reading in a file. This file contains a list of city names, high and low temperatures. Then, these are stored into the dynamic arrays after reading those lines, and grow the dynamic arrays if necessary (double the size).

Did I write something incorrect for this "grow" code function?

```
int i = 0;
if ( i >= arr1.size){    //arr1 is a int declared in a struct

    string *tempStr;  //temporary string
    tempStr = new string[arr1.size*2];

    int *tempInt;   //temporary int
    tempInt = new int[arr1.size*2];

    for (int a = 0; a < arr1.size; a++){
        tempStr[a] = arr1.cityName[a]; //cityName is a dynamic array declared in struct as a string
        tempInt[a] = arr1.hiTemp[a]; //hiTemp --> dynamic array declared in struct as an int
        tempInt[a] = arr1.loTemp[a]; //loTemp --> dynamic array declared in struct as an int

            }

    delete[] arr1.cityName;
    delete[] arr1.hiTemp;
    delete[] arr1.loTemp;

    arr1.cityName = tempStr;
    arr1.hiTemp = tempInt;
    arr1.loTemp = tempInt;

    arr1.size = arr1.size*2;   //doubling the size
}
i++;
```

Comment: `delete[] arr1.cityName;``delete[] arr1.hiTemp;``delete[] arr1.loTemp;` were those dynamically allocated? also, you're affecting `tempInt` to both `arr1.loTemp` and `arr1.hiTemp` could it be that you run this code twice and it actually frees `tempInt` twice?

Comment: Is there a reason not to use `std::vector`?

Comment: I second sfjac, `std::vector` would allow you not to worry about allocating and releasing your memory. Especially since you seem to have problems determining if you should delete both `arr1.hiTemp` and `arr1.loTemp` or only one of those.

Answer (score 1):

```
    tempInt[a] = arr1.hiTemp[a];
    tempInt[a] = arr1.loTemp[a];
```

You've using the same temp array for both.

And then you do:

```
arr1.hiTemp = tempInt;
arr1.loTemp = tempInt;
```

So now your struct has two different pointers pointing to the same array.

That means the next time something runs your grow algorithm on that struct, it'll get to:

```
delete[] arr1.hiTemp;
delete[] arr1.loTemp;
```

and consequently try to delete the same memory twice, which is of course very bad.

So you need to fix this to use two separate `new int` arrays.

(Or just replace all this with `std::vector`s since those are much easier to manage.)

Comment: Yes, I noticed that until I read Caninonos comments. The error is gone, but now the program doesn't output anything and just continues running.

Comment: @dendritic Then you might have other problems, perhaps in code outside of what's covered in this question. You could try stepping through in a debugger or putting in some `cout` statements to see what it's doing.